# Empty result when using properties Pizza.owl

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I'm trying to run the following SPARQL query in Protege 4.3 (on **[Pizza.owl](https://github.com/owlcs/pizza-ontology/blob/master/pizza.owl)**), but I get an empty result:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
SELECT ?pizzaInstance ?pizzaClass ?toppingInstance
WHERE {
?pizzaClass rdfs:subClassOf :NamedPizza .
?pizzaInstance rdf:type ?pizzaClass .
?pizzaInstance :hasTopping ?toppingInstance .
}
```

This only happens when I run queries involving **properties**.
With the same prefixes the following query works - and returns **NamedPizza**:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
SELECT ?pizzaInstance 
WHERE {
?pizzaInstance rdfs:subClassOf :Pizza .
}
```

What is wrong with the first query?

Comment: As you already figured out, `hasTopping` is only used in class expressions to define classes, e.g. `Pizza SubClassOf hasTopping some Topping` but not to relate instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally understood what I was doing wrong. This query returns **individuals** for pizzaInstance, and none of the individuals in my ontology had a topping. When I queried for `hasCalorificContentValue` instead of `hasTopping` I got the desired results:

```
PREFIX pz: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2017/11/Ontology1512823737278.owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?pizzaClass ?pizzaInstance ?calorificInstance
WHERE {
?pizzaClass rdfs:subClassOf pz:NamedPizza .
?pizzaInstance rdf:type ?pizzaClass.
?pizzaInstance pz:hasCalorificContentValue ?calorificInstance.
}
```

[image]

The query becomes meaningful when you check the raw owl file (*Example-MargheritaPizza is of type MargheritaPizza and is involved in the datatype property hasCalorificValue*):

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Ontology1512823737278;Example-MargheritaPizza">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Ontology1512823737278;MargheritaPizza"/>
        <hasCalorificContentValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;int">263</hasCalorificContentValue>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

[Here](http://wiltrud.hwro.de/teaching/semweb14w/slides/3A_SPARQL.handout.pdf) is a good tutorial, hope this helps someone.